# How to copy a set of cells based on the number entered

Tags: excel, vba

On my WS, I have a table with a schedule of values listed, broken down by labor and material, and on the other sheet is a set of perimeters (questions) that you input (number) into the cell.  Based on the number, I want to copy the table of values down the sheet (looped) that many times.
In other words, 'How many Elevators?' A3=6 in cell. When I run the macro, it copies the table on the other sheet that number of times (6-1=5) since the original is counted as one.

```
            Allocation %    Scheduled Value   Labor   Material  Total
```

Comment: Can you please give us sample data and the expected output, as well as what you've got so far and where the problem is exactly? You mention you run a macro, it would also be helpful to post the code for it. Please see: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything started in VBA since I'm not sure how to set it up.  This the results I'm looking for below.

Part of sheet 1 would be like this;

No. of Traction Banks:  5

No of Hydro Banks: 1

Total Elevators: 6

Results should take the following table and duplicate it down the second sheet like this:

ELEV #1
Schedule value  Material    Labor   Total   %
Drawings    0.00    0.00    0.00
Engineering     0.00    0.00    0.00

ELEV #2
Schedule value  Material    Labor   Total   %
Drawings    0.00    0.00    0.00
Engineering     0.00    0.00    0.00

ELEV #3
Schedule value  Material    Labor   Total   %
Drawings    0.00    0.00    0.00
Engineering     0.00    0.00    0.00

ELEV #4
Schedule value  Material    Labor   Total   %
Drawings    0.00    0.00    0.00
Engineering     0.00    0.00    0.00

ELEV #5
Schedule value  Material    Labor   Total   %
Drawings    0.00    0.00    0.00
Engineering     0.00    0.00    0.00

ELEV #6
Schedule value  Material    Labor   Total   %
Drawings    0.00    0.00    0.00
Engineering     0.00    0.00    0.00